# android initialize two times in two different activities

Tags: android

Not able to initialize parse two times in two another activity to call data from two classes of parse and put them in different list views. at second time when opening contact activity by action item then the app stops

Main Activity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private CountryAdapter mAdapter;   

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Parse.initialize(this, "0FgKGokshcBPQSpY**********", "f1hZ9W4c***********");

        ParseObject.registerSubclass(Country.class);


        mAdapter = new CountryAdapter(this, new ArrayList<Country>());

        ListView mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.country_list);
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        updateData();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_contact) {

            Intent i = new Intent(this, ContactActivity.class);

            startActivity(i);
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void updateData() {
        ParseQuery<Country> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Country.class);

        query.setCachePolicy(ParseQuery.CachePolicy.CACHE_THEN_NETWORK);
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Country>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<Country> countrys, com.parse.ParseException e) {

                if (countrys != null) {
                    mAdapter.clear();
                    for (int i = 0; i < countrys.size(); i++) {
                        mAdapter.add(countrys.get(i));
                    }
                }
            }
        });   
    }
}
```

ContactActivity.java

```
public class ContactActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private ContactAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact);

        Parse.initialize(this, "0FgKGoksh********************", "f1hZ9W4cKO2Ag*******************");

        ParseObject.registerSubclass(Contact.class);


        mAdapter = new ContactAdapter(this, new ArrayList<Contact>());

        ListView mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contact_list);
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


        updateData();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_contact, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void updateData() {
        ParseQuery<Contact> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Contact.class);

        query.setCachePolicy(ParseQuery.CachePolicy.CACHE_THEN_NETWORK);
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Contact>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<Contact> contact, com.parse.ParseException e) {

                if (contact != null) {
                    mAdapter.clear();
                    for (int i = 0; i < contact.size(); i++) {
                        mAdapter.add(contact.get(i));
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: you should initialize Parse only once in Application class

Comment: How and where tell me in some explanation Is parse should be initialized only in main and not in contact activity that what u r saying ?

Answer (score 2):

You should initialize parse in a class which extends `Application` class like this

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Parse.initialize(this, "xxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxx");
    }
}
```

and put application class name in manifest file like

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication" />
```

Comment: ok bro and after creating class my application is it necessary to remove initialization of parse from main activity

Comment: yes. you don't need to intitialize parse anywhere else. Please read parse docs for android. they have mentioned all this.